# How to do in listing order of given text

Tags: php, html

I have some contents in a variable and I want to put contents in `<li>` list after getting full stop.

suppose content is:

```
Lorem ipsum amet Lorem ipsum amet Lorem ipsum amet .Lorem ipsum amet Lorem ipsum amet ,Lorem ipsum amet Lorem ipsum amet .
```

Now I have to put content like this:-

```html
<li>Lorem ipsum amet Lorem ipsum amet Lorem ipsum amet .</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum amet Lorem ipsum amet ,Lorem ipsum amet Lorem ipsum amet .</li>
```

It should be automatically dynamic according content.

My code :- `<?php $content=$data['content']; echo $content; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an array:

```
echo "<ul>"; 
foreach($content as $item){
    echo "<li>$item</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

The foreach loop takes each item once a time from the $content, and prints it with the echo within.
Otherwise make it an array with the explode function which uses a delimiter. Which is in your case a dot.

```
$contentArray = explode('.', $content);
```

And then use the $contentArray in the foreach loop above

Comment: Thank you - @Perry kipkerrie